# Start long running background location update task on silent push notification

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-location

I want to track the user's current location in my iOS application in background as well as foreground mode on silent notification. The location Tracking start on silent notification & work fine on foreground mode but in background mode location update start & stop after approx. 180 sec it should be continuous like foreground mode. for background operation i am using  beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler .

Comment: You can get your location as u want. You can run your app more time in background mode

Comment: Start significant location monitoring in the foreground (and keep it running) and then you can start location updates in the background. There is no need for beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler.